# How to handle the Storage Queue using the WebJobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-notificationhub

I just started to use Azure as my mobile development as well as my web development. 
I am using NodeJs as my framework to work on the azure backend. I am using mobile services and web apps in the azure.

Here is the situation, I am using the Storage Queue from Azure and I am using webjob from my webapps to handle the storage queues. The messages in the queue are going to be sent out to each specific user via notification hub. (Push Notification)

So, the queues will have the size of the 50,000 or more queue messages. All these messages are used to push out the message to the user one by one. However, I tried to handle the queues using WebJob by scheduling 2minutes interval. I know that webjob wont run two instances when the schedule is currently running. 
Initially, I wanna use the webjob which run continuously but it will go to pending to restart once the script run finished. My assumption for the continuously running of webjob is that it will run under an endless loop for the script over and over again. until it caught exception or something wrong. My assumption goes wrong, where it will restart by it self once it succeeded the whole script. I know the restart can be adjusted to less than 60seconds but I am not sure whether this helps as I could a lot aysnc operation as well.

For my script, it will run 50,000 or more users messages in the loop. Then, it will send out the push message via Azure nodejs package and then upon return, then it will delete the messages so that it wont appear in the queue anymore. So, there will be some async operation for each loop in the action.

However, everything is working fine but the webjob only have execute maximum of 5 mins and then it will run again on next schedule. Meaning, it will only run to a maximum 5 mins regardless of the operation. I tried with 1,000 messages from the queue and everything works fine but when the messages go up to 5,000 and above, the time is not sufficient. Therefore, some of the async operation is not completed which cause the messages are not deleted.

Is there a way to extend the 5 mins execution time or other better ways to handle the Storage Queues. I looked into the Webjobs SDK but it is only limited to C# and Visual Studio. I am using Mac OSX and Javascript which I could not use.

Please advise as I wasted a lot of time figuring out whats best to handle the storage queue using webjobs but now it seems like it does not serve the purpose when the messages grow bigger and when it dealt with async operation with the total of only 5 mins execution time. I do not have any VM at the moments which I only use PAAS in azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your description:

> All these messages are used to push out the message to the user one by one
>
> it will run 50,000 or more users messages in the loop

So your requirement is to send each message in queue to user,and now you get all the messages in queue one time even the message size will get up to more then 50,000, and loop the messages for further operations?

If there is any misunderstanding, feel free to let me know.

In my opinion, cloud you get the top message of the queue at once, and send it to your user, so that it will remarkbly reduce the processing time and which can be set in a continuously webjob. You can refer to [How To: Peek at the Next Message](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/#how-to-peek-at-the-next-message) to see how to peek at the message in the front of a queue without removing it from the queue

### update

As I found you have mentioned that I also have a Web App in Node.js in your whole project architecture.
So I consider whether you can leverage continuous webjob in Web Apps to get one message and send to Notification Hub one time.
And here is my test code snippet:

```
var azureStorage = require('azure-storage'),
    azure = require('azure'),
    accountName = '<accountName>',
    accountKey = '<accountKey>';
var queueSvc = azureStorage.createQueueService(accountName, accountKey);
var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService('<notificationhub-name>', '<connectionstring>');
queueSvc.getMessages('myqueue', {numOfMessages:1}, function(error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
        // Message text is in messages[0].messagetext
        var message = result[0];
        console.log(message.messagetext);
        var payload = {
            data: {
                msg: message.messagetext
            }
        };
        notificationHubService.gcm.send(null, payload, function(error) {
            if (!error) {
                //notification sent
                console.log('notification sent');
                queueSvc.deleteMessage('myqueue', message.messageid,message.popreceipt,function(error, response) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.log(response);
                        // Message deleted
                    } else {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Details refer to [How to use Notification Hubs from Node.js](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-nodejs-how-to-use-notification-hubs/) And https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/queue/queueservice.js#L727

### update2

As I get the idea of [Service-bus demo on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus#how-to-use), I modified the code above, and which greatly improve the efficiency.

Here the code snippet, for your information:

```
var queueName = 'myqueue';

function checkForMessages(queueSvc, queueName, callback) {
    queueSvc.getMessages(queueName, function(err, message) {

        if (err) {
            if (err === 'No messages to receive') {
                console.log('No messages');
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                // callback(err);
            }
        } else {
            callback(null, message[0]);
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}

function processMessage(queueSvc, err, lockedMsg) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error on Rx: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Rx: ', lockedMsg);
        var payload = {
            data: {
                msg: lockedMsg.messagetext
            }
        };
        notificationHubService.gcm.send(null, payload, function(error) {
            if (!error) {
                //notification sent

                console.log('notification sent');
                console.log(lockedMsg)
                console.log(lockedMsg.popreceipt)
                queueSvc.deleteMessage(queueName, lockedMsg.messageid, lockedMsg.popreceipt, function(err2) {
                    if (err2) {
                        console.log('Failed to delete message: ', err2);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Deleted message.');
                    }
                })
            }
        });

    }
}

var t = setInterval(checkForMessages.bind(null, queueSvc, queueName, processMessage.bind(null, queueSvc)), 100);
```

I set the loop time as 100ms in `setInterval`, now it can process almost 600 message per minutes in my test.

Comment: Yes, but the continuously webjob somehow always goes into pending start once it run finish the script. Which means, the 50,000 messages or more will take a very long time to process all the messages. I know we can set the restart time for the webjob to be lesser which is the `WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME ` but then this would act like triggered webjob if the it keep restarting or should i set an endless loop inside the script for the continuously webjob? please advise :)

Comment: I consider whether you can leverage continuous webjob in Web Apps to get one message and send to Notification Hub one time, and update in the post.

Comment: And the continuous webjob runs one time every minutes, so we can leverage the option  `numOfMessages` in `getMessages()` function to control the message size be handled every time, to control the process time and the process efficiency

Comment: What if i get the total number of queues and loop the number of counts there and send via notification hub one at the time. For example, if i have 50,000 messages, then i would loop 50,000 times and everytime it will send out the messages. As the `numOfMessages` using the `queueSvc.getMessages`, maximum number of message only reach 32 messages at one time. Assuming 50,000, that is still a lot to process.

Comment: Thanks @GaryLiu, this seems alright when i am running this script via the continuously webjob. It could not be halted and get restarted now. Thanks again. This is something I wanted to handle the queues. In this case, I can handle as many messages by opening more concurrent webjobs to handle the webjobs as well.

Answer (score 0):

The various configuration settings for WebJobs are explained on [this wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs). In your case you should increase the `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` value, which is the time in seconds that a triggered job will timeout if it hasn't produced any output for a period of time. The `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` setting needs to be configured in the portal app settings, not via the app.config file.

Comment: I tried and put 600 seconds which is 10minutes. However, it also only executed for 5minutes as well. I even tried adjusting `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` but it does not help as well.

Comment: Since you had mentioned "5 mins and then it will run again on next schedule" I assumed you had a triggered WebJob running on a schedule. How exactly are you running - is it a Continuous WebJob? Are you running a Node.js continuous WebJob? If so, as long as your Node script continues to run (and doesn't return) WebJobs will keep the node.exe process running.

Comment: I am running the triggered webjobs which i set to 2 mins interval as this is to regular check whether there is any queue messages within 2 mins timeframe. When the triggered webjob is running, it will only for the maximum of 5 mins. That's the problem I am facing for the triggered webjobs. For the continous webjobs, I carry out a simple testing script with webhooks call to a service. However, once it succeed, it will goes to restart and run again after 60s. If the queue is to handle in Continuous webjob, should i include endless loop inside the script or just peek next messages?

Comment: How did you set `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT`? It needs to be set via the **portal app settings section**, not app.config file. Try that - it should work.

Comment: yea, i did try the `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT ` under the web-apps configure for the app setting using the [link](https://manage.windowsazure.com) . I tried this for the schedule webjobs. I will try on the webjob for continously and see how it goes. :)

Comment: I get this kind of response from the continuous webjob.
[01/27/2016 06:17:15 > 879d9b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
[01/27/2016 06:17:15 > 879d9b: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[01/27/2016 06:17:15 > 879d9b: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart

However, for this kind of problem, then it will only delete once per 60s as it success, they will restart again. For the 50,000 to be fully sent within the timeframe, then it would take a lot of time.